# Issues with GridView for the following UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to construct the following UI, but having issues with that. More specifically I tried different ways of doing this with GridView, but had no luck since I was not able to switch from 2 to 1 for crossAxisCount, because after showing the favorite cakes I need to "come back" to "normal" and show one block on one line for "Similar Products". Here is what I tried:

```
body: new LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraint) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: new GridView(
          gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: constraint.maxWidth / constraint.maxHeight,
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            // those widgets here will be created dynamically at the end
            // manually created a few just for illustration
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new MyFavoriteWidget(),
            new Container(
              child: Text("Similar Products"),
            ),
            // same for those widgets
            new SimilarProductWidget(),
            new SimilarProductWidget(),
            new SimilarProductWidget(),
            new SimilarProductWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

But this renders just 2 columns, which is what I want for the top part, but after the list of MyFavoriteWidget() I need to switch to normal layout and have one block on one line. And if I take this part out of the GridView it won't be visible. I feel like GridView is still the best way of implementing this but was not able to find a way around it. Even a skeleton code to get started or a hint how to overcome this issue will be much helpful.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: @AliMohammadzadeh updated !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer you try this code. For top list use `GridView.count` and for bottom list use `ListView.builder`. I give you a simple example to understand it. Run code below and see the result.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your heading'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: List.generate(
                6,
                (index) => Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 70,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                    width: double.infinity,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
```